# How to resolve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: database, oracle

When trying to connect to an `ORACLE` user via TOAD (Quest Software) or any other means (`Oracle Enterprise Manager`) I get this error:

> `ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`

Answer (score 103, accepted):

After some googling, I found the advice to do the following, and it worked:

```
SQL> startup mount

ORACLE Instance started

SQL> recover database 

Media recovery complete

SQL> alter database open;

Database altered
```

Comment: Second fragment worked for me too! One minor syntax issue, semi-colon is required in last "alter database open" command.

Comment: Old thread but thought I'd just add that the second fragment worked for me too.

Comment: After first fragment I got the following, but the database recover, resolved my issue. ERROR at line 1: ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [kcratr_scan_lastbwr], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

Comment: After `startup mount;` i have received ORA-011033 and `alter database open;` help me to fix my problem. I haven't execute recovery command.

Comment: the last command of the first fragment, à`alter database open;` gave `ERROR at line 1: ORA-01172: recovery of thread 1 stuck at block 27639 of file 3 ORA-01151: use media recovery to recover block, restore backup if needed` but I did `shutdown` then the second fragment and it worked.

Comment: very helpful. I followed the steps .. got the error and the second part resolved it. Thanks.

Comment: For me **worked so**: `SQL> connect sys@orcl12c/oracle as sysdba`  **Documentation** for command: Usage: `CONN[ECT] [{logon|/|proxy} [AS {SYSDBA|SYSOPER|SYSASM|SYSBACKUP|SYSDG|SYSKM|SYSRAC}] [edition=value]]`
where `<logon> ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]
      <proxy> ::= <proxyuser>[<username>][/<password>][@<connect_identifier>]`

Comment: but how did you get into sqlplus

Answer (score 32):

Here is my solution to this issue:

```
SQL> Startup mount
ORA-01081: cannot start already-running ORACLE - shut it down first
SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL>
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1904054272 bytes
Fixed Size                  2404024 bytes
Variable Size             570425672 bytes
Database Buffers         1325400064 bytes
Redo Buffers                5824512 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> Show parameter control_files

NAME                                 TYPE        VALUE
------------------------------------ ----------- ------------------------------
control_files                        string      C:\APP\USER\ORADATA\ORACLEDB\C
                                                 ONTROL01.CTL, C:\APP\USER\FAST
                                                 _RECOVERY_AREA\ORACLEDB\CONTRO
                                                 L02.CTL
SQL> select a.member,a.group#,b.status from v$logfile a ,v$log b where a.group#=
b.group# and b.status='CURRENT'
  2
SQL> select a.member,a.group#,b.status from v$logfile a ,v$log b where a.group#=
b.group# and b.status='CURRENT';

MEMBER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    GROUP# STATUS
---------- ----------------
C:\APP\USER\ORADATA\ORACLEDB\REDO03.LOG
         3 CURRENT


SQL> shutdown abort
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup mount
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1904054272 bytes
Fixed Size                  2404024 bytes
Variable Size             570425672 bytes
Database Buffers         1325400064 bytes
Redo Buffers                5824512 bytes
Database mounted.
SQL> recover database using backup controlfile until cancel;
ORA-00279: change 4234808 generated at 01/21/2014 18:31:05 needed for thread 1
ORA-00289: suggestion :
C:\APP\USER\FAST_RECOVERY_AREA\ORACLEDB\ARCHIVELOG\2014_01_22\O1_MF_1_108_%U_.AR

C
ORA-00280: change 4234808 for thread 1 is in sequence #108


Specify log: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
C:\APP\USER\ORADATA\ORACLEDB\REDO03.LOG
Log applied.
Media recovery complete.
SQL> alter database open resetlogs;

Database altered.
```

And it worked:

[image]

Comment: I was persistently getting oracle initialization or shutdown in progress. With this I was able to workaround this problem. But still my em service is not up and I am not able to access it on web.

Comment: Make sure all Oracle services are enabled . Take a look here for more info> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B16276_01/doc/server.102/b14196/em_manage002.htm

Comment: I tried many things.. In the end it gave up saying "A service specific error occurred: 2" without giving any additional error.

Comment: after trying so many solutions around, this second solution works amazingly well for me! Thank you So much.  Just a tip  , the last part.. REDO{O- capital letter}0{0 - ZERO number}3.LOG

Comment: I also ran into similar problem in Oracle12c- ORA-00742: Log read detects lost write in thread 1 sequence...
Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 22):

I had a similar problem when I had installed the 12c database as per [Oracle's tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/12c/r1/Windows_DB_Install_OBE/Installing_Oracle_Db12c_Windows.html) . The instruction instructs reader to create a PLUGGABLE DATABASE (pdb).

### The problem

`sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl` would result in **`ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress`**.

### The solution

- 1. **Login as `SYSDBA` to the dabase** :

     ```
     sqlplus SYS/Oracle_1@pdborcl AS SYSDBA
     ```
- 2. **Alter database**:

     ```
     alter pluggable database pdborcl open read write;
     ```
- 3. **Login again**:

     ```
     sqlplus hr/hr@pdborcl
     ```

*That worked for me*

Some documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_2008.htm#SQLRF55667)

Comment: Hey. I had exactly the same problem with pluggable database, although I used the following solution: https://community.oracle.com/message/14010401#14010401

Comment: This is quite a useful answer for beginners to Oracle, given that it mentions pluggable databases. Worked flawlessly which otherwise would have taken hours to search for.

Comment: None of the other answers worked for me but this worked like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: This solution solved the problem I was getting while following the tutorial http://www.oracletutorial.com/getting-started/create-oracle-sample-database-for-practice/
None of the other solutions did the trick.

Comment: Thank you. Its worked. since my pluggable database is different for Oracle 12.2.0 so I was using "alter pluggable database pdborcl open read write;"

Answer (score 6):

This error can also occur in the normal situation when a database is starting or stopping. Normally on startup you can wait until the startup completes, then connect as usual. If the error persists, the *service* (on a Windows box) may be started without the *database* being started. This may be due to startup issues, or because the service is not configured to automatically start the database. In this case you will have to connect as sysdba and physically start the database using the "startup" command.

Answer (score 4):

I used a combination of the answers from rohancragg, Mukul Goel, and NullSoulException from above. However I had an additional error:

ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file string - see DBWR trace file

To which I found the answer here: http://nimishgarg.blogspot.com/2014/01/ora-01157-cannot-identifylock-data-file.html

Incase the above post gets deleted I am including the commands here as well.

```
C:\>sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Tue Apr 30 19:07:16 2013
Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.
Connected to an idle instance.

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.
Total System Global Area  778387456 bytes
Fixed Size                  1384856 bytes
Variable Size             520097384 bytes
Database Buffers          251658240 bytes
Redo Buffers                5246976 bytes
Database mounted.
ORA-01157: cannot identify/lock data file 11 – see DBWR trace file
ORA-01110: data file 16: 'E:\oracle\app\nimish.garg\oradata\orcl\test_ts.dbf'

SQL> select NAME from v$datafile where file#=16;
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
E:\ORACLE\APP\NIMISH.GARG\ORADATA\ORCL\TEST_TS.DBF

SQL> alter database datafile 16 OFFLINE DROP;
Database altered.

SQL> alter database open;
Database altered.
```

Thanks everyone you saved my day!

Fissh

Answer (score 2):

The issue can also be due to lack of hard drive space. The installation will succeed but on startup, oracle won't be able to create the required files and will fail with the same above error message.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will help somebody, I solved the problem like this

There was a problem because the database was not open.
Command startup opens the database.

This you can solve with command `alter database open` 
in some case with  `alter database open resetlogs`

```
$ sqlplus / sysdba

SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1073741824 bytes
Fixed Size          8628936 bytes
Variable Size         624952632 bytes
Database Buffers      436207616 bytes
Redo Buffers            3952640 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.

SQL> conn user/pass123
Connected.
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. I restarted the oracle service for that DB instance and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that i hadn't set the local_listener, to see if the local listener is set login to `sqlplus / as sysdba`, make sure the database is open and run the following command
`show parameter local_listener`, if the value is empty,  then you will have to set the local_listener with the following SQL command `ALTER SYSTEM SET LOCAL_LISTENER='<LISTENER_NAME_GOES_HERE>'`