# oracle initialization exception

Tags: exception, oracle11g

I got an exception when i want to start oracle which is

> Erorr:ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

this is the first time I face this problem, DBMS asks me to wait and then restart the system , since yesterday and i am trying to start it ,but I couldn't make it.

please can someone help!

Comment: Try to re-read the tititletion of your questition

Comment: @ belisarius- what do u mean with tititletion ?

Comment: Alaa.. the title says "ininatiation" instead of "initialization".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error message indicates, this means that the database is currently either initializing or is shutting down.

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress 
Cause: An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up or shutdown. 
Action: Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation.
```

Sometimes, if one of the files needed for initialization is corrupted or needs recovery, you might see this message for ever. This is what you can do to see what the actual error is and then start debugging from there.

From your command prompt logon as sysdba

```
sqlplus /nolog
connect / as sysdba
```

Do a shutdown and a clean startup.

```
shutdown immediate;
startup;
```

This should indicate what is causing the issue and you'll be able to fix it.

A couple of useful links.

[How to resolve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress)

http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=338394