# oracle initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm getting error: `oracle initialization or shutdown in progress` for a oracle database when connecting to it. I have oracle 11g installed in my machine. I cant even able to access my sql plus using "sys" account. Is there any way to know what is the sys account password in the oracle database?

Comment: How did you attempt to access sys? It could be that the connection string is incorrect rather than the password.

Comment: i used in cmd prompt > sqlplus / as sysdba. it is throwing ERROR:
ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Answer (score 0):

**In linux**... kill oracle processes. `pkill -9 -f oracle`

Then `sqlplus / as sysdba` and run

`SQL>startup force`

Then exit and from shell run `lsnrctl start`

**In Windows**... Restart `OracleService<SIDName>` in Windows services. And follow the same.

Make sure path is set in both env.for commands to work.

Similar to [How to resolve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress?rq=1)

Comment: This is not necessarily good advice; it would be better to _wait_ for the initialization or shutdown to finish.

Comment: How long do you wait?  24 hours?  48 hours?