# ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress can't connect to HR

Tags: oracle

I am trying to open oracle and connect to the HR schema but I got this error. I don't know how to fix it:

```
ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Cause: an attempt was made to log in while oracle is being started up or shutdown
```

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for edited my question, I'm learning English also

Comment: Refer to my post about HR: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress/43871217#43871217

Answer (score 1):

Your oracle instance is, as the error message says, in the middle of shutting down or starting up. Wait for it to shut down properly, start it up again, and then connect.

Comment: am waiting since one hour and i already restarted the computer ,, still have it

Comment: The oracle database is on your computer? Are you sure?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps :

1. From your OS command line, issue

   `sqlplus sys@service_name as sysdba`
2. On prompt, provide the `password.
3. `shutdown immediate`
4. Wait for the step 3 to complete.
5. `startup`
6. Wait for step 5 to complete.

If step 5 is clean, you should not face any issues further.

Comment: i can't write anything on the promt screen, it seems problem on my device!

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you said. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: And if you exhaust these options, you may need to try a `shutdown abort`.