# Unable to connect to Oracle DB - ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

Tags: database, oracle

When I am trying to connect the oracle DB it throws the following error:

```
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
```

I searched over the net and got few solutions but no luck. Even I restarted the database and the DB started without any error. Following are the logs:

```
Enter user-name: /as sysdba

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing options

SQL> shutdown immediate
Database closed.
Database dismounted.
ORACLE instance shut down.
SQL> startup
ORACLE instance started.

Total System Global Area 1.0167E+10 bytes
Fixed Size                  2934888 bytes
Variable Size            1677723544 bytes
Database Buffers         8455716864 bytes
Redo Buffers               30617600 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
SQL> exit

Enter user-name: rc532/rc532@abcdb
ERROR:
ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

After restart I checked the following:

```
SQL> select status, database_status from v$instance;

STATUS       DATABASE_STATUS
------------ -----------------
OPEN         ACTIVE

SQL> select open_mode from v$database;

OPEN_MODE
--------------------
READ WRITE
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress?rq=1

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I already tried but no luck. I have provided the logs

Comment: since you are using 12c its possible that your pluggable database didnt start when you started the container database.. What does this statement give you `SELECT name, open_mode FROM v$pdbs` ?

Comment: I think it is the prob. it gives `ABCDB                MOUNTED`. How can resolve it?

Comment: Alterd PLUGGABLE DATABASE and now its working fine. Thanks @cableload

Comment: Also since you are on 12.1.0.2.0 you can use the following statement `ALTER PLUGGABLE DATABASE "yourpdb" SAVE STATE` Then you dont have to start the pdb everytime you restart the container

Answer (score 2):

This can happen when the pluggable database isn't open. To open it use

```
# Start the mypdb pluggable database (if not already running)
SQL> alter pluggable database mypdb open read write;

# Make the read/write state permanent across reboots
SQL> alter pluggable database all save state;
```