# Facing Issues during Login to application and getting errors related to WSO2

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-identity-server

We are facing an issue while login to an application and getting issues related to WSO2. So here i have given error from 2 latest log files taken today. Please let us know if anyone has faced a similar kind of issue .

1. When checked in WSO2 AM log path : ../../ wso2am-2.1.0  folder for log files, got the below error :

TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 00:00:47,106] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter} -  Error when reporting timers {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter}
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Internal Error: Underflow Exception trying to bind 2.964393875E-314
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.reportTimers(JDBCReporter.java:389)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.report(JDBCReporter.java:200)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 00:01:47,195] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter} -  Error when reporting timers {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter}
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Internal Error: Underflow Exception trying to bind 2.964393875E-314
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.reportTimers(JDBCReporter.java:389)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.report(JDBCReporter.java:200)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2. When checked in the WSO2 IS  log path :../../wso2is-5.3.0  folder for log files, got the below error :

TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 00:07:35,909]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.SessionCleanUpService} -  Session Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Data 
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 06:22:37,429]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.store.OperationCleanUpService} -  Session Operation Data cleanup task is running successfully for removing expired Operation Data 
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 09:46:49,098] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler} -  Database error upgrading jobs. 
 org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

```
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.narrow(DBDictionary.java:4918)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.DBDictionary.newStoreException(DBDictionary.java:4878)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:136)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:110)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.sql.SQLExceptions.getStore(SQLExceptions.java:62)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:949)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.retainConnection(JDBCStoreManager.java:226)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.retainConnection(DelegatingStoreManager.java:164)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.retainConnection(BrokerImpl.java:3986)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beginStoreManagerTransaction(BrokerImpl.java:1430)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.beginStore(BrokerImpl.java:1415)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreQuery.executeBulkOperation(JDBCStoreQuery.java:566)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreQuery.executeUpdate(JDBCStoreQuery.java:498)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ExpressionStoreQuery$DataStoreExecutor.executeUpdate(ExpressionStoreQuery.java:806)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.update(QueryImpl.java:1056)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:867)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl.updateAll(QueryImpl.java:904)
at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingQuery.updateAll(DelegatingQuery.java:598)
at org.apache.openjpa.persistence.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:377)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.dao.jpa.openjpa.HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.updateAssignToNode(HumanTaskDAOConnectionImpl.java:277)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$3.call(SimpleScheduler.java:485)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$3.call(SimpleScheduler.java:480)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:879)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.execTransaction(SimpleScheduler.java:828)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler.doUpgrade(SimpleScheduler.java:480)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$UpgradeJobsTask.run(SimpleScheduler.java:450)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:149)
at org.wso2.carbon.humantask.core.scheduler.SimpleScheduler$1.call(SimpleScheduler.java:146)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:441)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:404)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:385)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:278)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.reconnect(PooledConnection.java:315)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:794)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:619)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:188)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:128)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DelegatingDataSource.getConnection(DelegatingDataSource.java:110)
at org.apache.openjpa.lib.jdbc.DecoratingDataSource.getConnection(DecoratingDataSource.java:87)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connectInternal(JDBCStoreManager.java:960)
at org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.connect(JDBCStoreManager.java:945)
... 26 more
```

Comment: **java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress** this is discussed in the following question, did you try it?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress

Comment: Getting the below error  in JMS .  Please follow the below link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835384/hi-all-getting-the-below-error-does-anyone-have-ever-faced-a-similar-issue

Comment: @Sajith: getting the error connecting issue in jms.. Please see the updated link. As i could not paste the complete code . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52835384/hi-all-getting-the-below-error-does-anyone-have-ever-faced-a-similar-issue

Comment: what is the application that you are trying to login?