# Hi All, Getting the below error. Does anyone have ever faced a similar issue.?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-identity-server, wso2-esb

Getting the below error. Does anyone have ever faced a similar issue.?

```
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 08:10:31,330] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory} -  Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData} {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory}
org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.OutputEventAdapterRuntimeException: Error acquiring a Connection from the JMS CF : jmsEventPublisher using properties : {transport.jms.ConcurrentPublishers=allow, java.naming.provider.url=repository/conf/jndi.properties, java.naming.factory.initial=org.wso2.andes.jndi.PropertiesFileInitialContextFactory, transport.jms.DestinationType=topic, transport.jms.ConnectionFactoryJNDIName=TopicConnectionFactory, transport.jms.Destination=throttleData}
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.handleException(JMSConnectionFactory.java:197)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:278)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory$PoolableJMSConnectionFactory.makeObject(JMSConnectionFactory.java:356)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1181)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.getConnectionFromPool(JMSConnectionFactory.java:286)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:86)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:361)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:40)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSUtils.createConnection(JMSUtils.java:387)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSConnectionFactory.createConnection(JMSConnectionFactory.java:268)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.AMQConnectionFailureException: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:486)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionFactory.createConnection(AMQConnectionFactory.java:351)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.wso2.andes.transport.TransportException: Could not open connection
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport$IoConnectorCreator.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:216)
    at org.wso2.andes.transport.network.mina.MinaNetworkTransport.connect(MinaNetworkTransport.java:74)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnectionDelegate_8_0.java:130)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:631)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection$2.run(AMQConnection.java:628)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.makeBrokerConnection(AMQConnection.java:628)
    at org.wso2.andes.client.AMQConnection.<init>(AMQConnection.java:409)
    ... 14 more
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 08:10:31,332] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender} -   {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.internal.util.JMSMessageSender.send(JMSMessageSender.java:88)
    at org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.jms.JMSEventAdapter$JMSSender.run(JMSEventAdapter.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
TID: [-1] [] [2018-10-11 08:10:47,331] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter} -  Error when reporting timers {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter}
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Internal Error: Underflow Exception trying to bind 2.964393875E-314
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10345)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.reportTimers(JDBCReporter.java:389)
    at org.wso2.carbon.metrics.jdbc.reporter.JDBCReporter.report(JDBCReporter.java:200)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter.report(ScheduledReporter.java:162)
    at com.codahale.metrics.ScheduledReporter$1.run(ScheduledReporter.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Please elaborate the product (any? all? marked), versions, describe the setup. Apparently you've made some configuration that may not be valid or oyu did not initialize databases or using unsupported versions. I suggest to make any configuration updates step-by-step and not all at once, then could know where you have scr.... misconfigured something

Comment: You can add more information regarding the configuration that you have made

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your JMS connection is not correct because the server was unable to establish the connection. Review your entire JMS connection.

```
Caused by: javax.jms.JMSException: Error creating connection: Could not open connection
```