# Is there any way to fix ORA-01033 Oracle initialization or shutdown in progress issue without actually having sysdba access to the database?

Tags: oracle, windows-7

We have this old software that with local oracle db. The computer started crashing yesterday. Somehow I was able to bring it back to life, but now I keep getting this "ORA-01033" error whenever trying to start the software. And unfortunately I do not have admin dba access to the database. So I can't try this guide

[How to resolve ORA-011033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53676/how-to-resolve-ora-011033-oracle-initialization-or-shutdown-in-progress)

So far I've tried

```
restarting the computer

restarting OracleService in "services"

restarting "Oracle TNS listener in "services"
```

Any tip would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Correction of the problem will almost certainly require DBA access. What version of Oracle? Is it really running on Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below
sqlplus
shutdown abort
startup mount
recover database
alter database open
alter database open resetlogs

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).